# No puedo imprimir los resultados que introduzco de mi array con objetos

Tags: javascript

pues como habrán leído tengo este javascript con el que al introducir una serie de datos que pido por pantalla se impriman los datos, la cosa es que lo unico que aparece al poner los datos es si el profesor existe, no imprime ni el resto de datos del alumno.
Además tengo un error con el innerhtml que dice tal que asi:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'innerHTML') at mensaje.js:74

A continuación adjunto código html y javascript

html:

```
 <button onclick="infoalumno()">Informacion del alumno</button>
    <button onclick="insertar()">Introducir nuevo alumno</button>
    <div id="info"></div>
```

y javascript:

```
function alumno(nombre, edad, nota, profesor) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nota = nota;
    this.profesor = profesor;
}

function profesor(nombre, asginatura) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.asginatura = asginatura;
}

var profesores = new Array(3);
profesores[0] = new profesor("Paco","Plastica");
profesores[1] = new profesor("Anton","Biologia");
profesores[2] = new profesor("Jacinto","Lengua");

var alumnos = new Array(2);
alumnos[0] = new alumno("Jose",24,7,profesores[0]);
alumnos[1] = new alumno("Jacobo",23,7,profesores[2]);


function infoalumno() {

    var buscar = prompt("Inserta el nombre del alumno que quieres buscar");

    var comprobar = false
    for (let i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
        if (buscar == alumnos[i].nombre) {
            document.write("Nombre" + alumnos[i].nombre + "<br>Edad:" + alumnos[i].edad + "<br>Nota:" + alumnos[i].nota + "<br>Profesor:" + alumnos[i].profesor.nombre);
            comprobar = true;
        }
        if (comprobar == false) {
            document.write("Alumno " + buscar + "no existe");
        }
    }
}

function insertar() {

    var comprobar2 = false;

    var nombre = prompt("Insertar el nombre del alumno");
    var edad = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la edad"));
    var nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la nota"));
    var profesor = prompt("¿Quien es el profesor?");
    for (let i = 0; i < profesores.length; i++) {
        if (profesor == profesores[i].nombre) {
            var newalumno = new alumno(nombre, edad, nota, profesor[i].nombre);
            alumnos.push(newalumno);
            comprobar2=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(comprobar2==false){
        document.write("Profesor "+profesor+" no existe");
    }
}

var infoprofesor ="Profesores";
for (let i = 0; i < profesores.length; i++) {
   infoprofesor = infoprofesor + profesores[i].nombre+"<br>";
    
}

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = infoprofesor;
```

Comment: No es buena idea usar `document.write()` para agregar contenido al HTML, porque no se tiene control de dónde se inserta el nuevo texto. Deberías crear elementos y agregarlos con [.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) a un contenedor específico. Para los errores, podrías usar una alerta o solo mostrarlos en consola.

Comment: En cuanto al erro del elemento que no existe, probablemente tienes el script arriba, antes de crear el HTML y la solución es sencilla: Coloca el script hasta abajo (antes de `</body>` o, mejor aún, haz que se ejecute hasta que [se haya cargado el DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dijo Triby tu codigo esta correcto el problema al parecer es el orden:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <button onclick="infoalumno()">Informacion del alumno</button>
        <button onclick="insertar()">Introducir nuevo alumno</button>
        <div id="info">

        </div>
    </form>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mensaje.js"></script>  
</body>
```

debes llamar al script `<script type="text/javascript" src="mensaje.js"></script>` despues de haber creado la pagina sino nunca reconocera el id info en `document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = infoprofesor;`.